# SQL Server: Why are scans occurring even though seeks are used?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I understand what an index seek is vs. an index scan.  In this specific case, I'm trying to understand why sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats shows scans occurring even though seeks are present.

The query against sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats shows the following:

```
name     user_scans   user_seeks   user_lookups
Index 1           0        22808              0
Index 2           0        71768              0
Index 3          77         1932              0
Index 4           2         6585              0
Index 5           0       104363              0
Index 6           0        24571              0
Index 7           0         8776              0
```

I've combed through the stored procedure code and it looks like every query's WHERE clause is covered by one of these indexes.  Given that, I assumed that there would be no need to scan as the seek should satisfy the query.  Am I misunderstanding how this works? Or is my assumption correct and I must just be missing some queries that aren't satisfied by the seek?

Comment: One thing that's good to remember is that even if you have an index it's not up to you whether the database will use it or not. There may be a large % of rows being pulled in which case database decided to deliver the results using `user_scan` rather than `user_seek`. You could do some data profiling to see if that may be the case.

Comment: @KamilG. is correct about the large number of rows returned. Consider this situation. You have an index on (say) `DateShipped, DateReceived, CustomerId` and Includes `InventoryId, QtyShipped`. Someone runs a query that wants to identify all items shipped during the last five years, and how many items have been shipped. The DB has data for the last six years. The optimizer will probably decide that it will be faster to do an index scan than an index seek, since the vast majority of the data will be examined. That's one way to get a scan.

Comment: tl;dr Scans are sometimes more efficient than Seeks, and will be used if the Optimizer thinks that will be the case.